# Using Android Open Source Code

Tags: android

This is kind of just a general question. I am relatively new to Android programming and I find myself constantly on the android tutorials to get help on topics I want. Consequently a lot of my code resembles such tutorials. Is it bad for me to publish these applications if they use the android code tailored to my needs?

Thanks for your help. I know these moral issues are kind of tough.

Comment: read the legal stuff on the site

Answer (score 1):

If you take refernce from other android code written and released by others, check the license for the code and according use it in your code and can publish your app. For example any code released under GPL license can we used directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are very helpful Tutorials:

http://vogella.com

http://androidhive.com.info

Answer (score 0):

Not really - the purpose of these tutorials are to help you get started on your application. They are meant to serve as templates. But if you are taking licensed code from somewhere then you might want to be extra careful. But as long as you are using tutorials as just a template for your application, you are fine.